# How to match two or more words name in javascript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to verify that there are at least two words name, where a word is only alphabet for example:

```
// Should pass
Jean Acker 
Mary Kay Adams
Elizabeth Allen Alba Bailey
Blanche Baker Bowen Collinge Marie
// ...and so on more than two words

// Should Fail
Ryan
Filbert77
Mark 21
Franz.Dimaz
```

This is the regex I'm currently using just to verify letters and spaces

```
/^[aA-zZ\s]+$/
```

I have searched and tried one of them on this link but it didn't work [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746846/how-to-match-two-or-more-words)

Can anyone help me to verify name more than 1 word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

([a-zA-Z]{1,})+\s+([a-zA-Z]{1,})+[a-zA-Z\s]*

Answer (score 0):

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/tt4H3Q/1

Pattern : `[a-zA-Z]+(?: [a-zA-Z]+)+`

`[a-zA-Z]` -> Match only alphabets

`+` -> Match the pattern one or more times